# retain selected options from dropdown after form submission in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, coffeescript

There are lot of answers on rataining selected options from dropdown after form submission but my usecase little different. I have a `<select>` element with id `someId` and the `<select>` element has lot options (exceeds 1000) so when form submission is done all those options are appended in url as parameters. so because of too long url I am getting 414 in order to deal it I have made changes in code where if all the optiions are selected I am appending parameter as selectAll

```
$('form#searchForm').submit ->
    if $("#someId option:not(:selected)").length == 0
       $('#someId').val "selectAll"
```

what i am doing to retain all the selected options is

```
$ ->
    someValue = localStorage.getItem('someId')
    if someValue != null
      $('select[name=someIdName]').val someValue
    $('select[name=someIdName]').on 'change', ->
      localStorage.setItem 'someId  ', $(this).val()
      return
    return
```

since I am doing this on form submission

```
if $("#someId option:not(:selected)").length == 0
       $('#somneId').val "selectAll"
```

I am kind of loosing all the options in runtime and I am not able to retain any of the checked options after form submission.
Retaining the selected options is working if selectAll is not checked. please help